Push forward a Hermitian line bundle on Riemann surface
Let $\pi :Y\to X$ be a ramified n-sheets covering map between two Riemann surfaces. $(L,h)$ is a Hermitian line bundle over $Y$ or we can regard it as a locally free $O_{Y}$-module of rank $1$. Then we can show that $\pi_{*}(L)$ is a locally free $O_{X}$-module of rank $n$.
To see this, let us pick in the ramification locus a point $p\in X$ and a point $q\in \pi^{-1}(p)$ with multiplicity $r$. Then in appropriate centered coodinate disks ($U_{q}$,z) and ($V_{p}$,w), the map $\pi$ looks like $w=\pi(z)=z^{r}$. By the definition of direct image of sheaves, we have $\pi_{*}(L)(V)=L(U)\cong O_{Y}(U)$. But $\pi^{*}(O_{X}(V))\cong O_{Y}(U)$ is a subsheaf(also subring) of $O_{Y}(U)$, we can denote it as $O_{Y}'(U)$. In this sense, $O_{Y}(U)\cong O_{Y}'(U)\oplus zO_{Y}'(U)\oplus\cdots z^{r-1}O_{Y}'(U)$ is a free $O_{Y}'(U)$ module of rank $r$. Using the isomorphism $\pi^{*}(O_{X}(V))\cong O_{Y}(U)$, we can endow the sheaf $\pi_{*}(L)$ with a $O_{X}$-module structure with which $\pi_{*}(L)$ is obviously locally free of rank $n$.
My question is how to push forward the metric to the vector bundle $\pi_{*}(L)$?

There is an obvious metric locally on each summand; can you not declare the different summands to be orthogonal?

sorry, I didn't express myself well. I will modify my question.

can we extend the metric to p?

How does the direct sum decomposition you have at $p$ relate to the direct sum decomposition on a nearby open subset?

I haven't think about it yet. I need to figure out the transformation matrix.
